# Bootstrap/jQuery event binding issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

I'm implementing Twitter Bootstrap on a current project and am having a hell of a time binding event handlers on `$(document)`. They're basically being ignored. If I bind them to `$("body")`, they work fine -- to a degree.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li><a href="/edit_status/1174" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>  Change Status</a></li>
```

Here's the JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "a[data-toggle=modal]", on_click_data_toggle);
function on_click_data_toggle(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
    if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
        $(url).modal('open');
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(data){
                if(data.length > 0)
                {
                    $('<div class="modal hide fade">' + data + '</div>').modal();
                }
            },
            error: function(){
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When the event is bound through "body" it works except that the console keeps displaying the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /edit_status/1348

The code executes fine but it makes me think there is something else amiss that would've been causing the `$(document).on` approach to not work either.

I've read that the Javascript error usually means there's a selector issue but the code does execute so I'm thoroughly confused.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whats the value of `url` when you get the syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have more jQuery code that you're not showing, but if not, you're missing the closing bracket and parenthesis on both the click delegate and the ready delegate. I also moved your function to be an anonymous function:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "a[data-toggle=modal]", function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
            $(url).modal('open');
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.length > 0)
                    {
                        $('<div class="modal hide fade">' + data + '</div>').modal();
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

From just a quick glance, this should work. Using the anonymous function like this (within the delegate) makes it more obvious what `this` would point to (in this case, the anchor that triggered the click event).

**FWIW**, the modal plugin does have a `remote` option that would likely accomplish the same result as what you're trying to do here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: Wow! I totally did not see that remote option on the documentation!

Comment: As an aside, if I include the attribute data-target="#" or "#modal" it fixes both the "unrecognized expression" error and the inability to just the $(document).on syntax! Looks like I just needed to RTFM!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link7) for an explanation of how events bubble up to the document. All things being equal, the document click handler should work (see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiftyp/Mhwth/)).  The case where it wouldn't is if a click handler on an child node (in this case the body) stops the event propogation.  My guess is that one of the plugins you are using is doing this.  Try making a page with a click handler on the document (or use my fiddle), and add your plugins one by one to see what is causing the problem.

```
$(document).click(function(){
    alert('You clicked me!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to using toggle-model attribitue of bootstrap to open a model popup, 
instead of use this code without any class,  in mvc Action link or htnl page..
If you have any suggestion than send me mail : vishalroxx7@gmail.com

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"><div class="te">Please wait...</div></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>*@
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->








    $(document).ready(function () {
      //  $('.dialog-window').attr("data-target", "#myModal"); // this is used when you oen a single link on a page 
        //   $('.dialog-window').attr("data-toggle", "modal"); /// this is used to attache dyanaic call to anchor tag or action link 


        $("body").on("click", "a.dialog-window", null, function (e)
        {              
            e.preventDefault();


            var $link = $(this); // Reference to <a/> link
            var title = $link.text();// this is title to fetch in htnl    
            $('#myModal .modal-title').html(title);

            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
            else
            {

                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $('#myModal .te').html(data);
                    $('#myModal').modal();
                }).success(function () { $('input:text:visible:first').focus(); });

            }

        });
    });

</script>
```